# Java application command-line start

Tags: java

"java -cp . name" - string to put it in command-line.
What is -cp in this string? Google just does not want to search it.

Comment: If you wan't to google it then add add quotes like `"-cp"` if you search for `-cp` then google thinks you want to exclude cp from your search results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the classpath:

> -classpath classpath
>
> -cp classpath
>
> Specify a list of directories, JAR archives, and ZIP archives to search for class files. Class path entries are separated by semicolons (;). Specifying -classpath or -cp overrides any setting of the CLASSPATH environment variable.
> If -classpath and -cp are not used and CLASSPATH is not set, the user class path consists of the current directory (.).
> For more information on class paths, see Setting the Class Path.

From http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html

A single full-stop means the current working directory - so in your above call, it's setting the classpath as such.

Answer (score 3):

[`-cp` is a synonym for `-classpath`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html#options).  [The Classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) tells the JVM where to find the `.class` files containing the code it needs to run.  It is a list of directories and/or `JAR` files.

So in your example `-cp .` is setting the Classpath to contain just the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query: http://www.google.cz/search?q=java+%22-cp%22 and as others said it's for setting classpath. If you google word "minus"-something, you need to surround it with quotation marks. Otherwise you exclude such word from your search (it's the function of minus sign in Google).